# "Paraphrasing" an equation

Tags: vocabulary

> Three Laws of Thermodynamics (paraphrased): First Law:  You can't get
>   anything without working for it. Second Law: The most you can
>   accomplish by work is to break even. Third Law:  You can't break even.

I stumbled across [the above joke](http://jcdverha.home.xs4all.nl/scijokes/2_18.html) (from the webmaster's viewpoint, but see jwpat7's comment) and it made me wonder if "paraphrasing an equation" can be used in a more formal context. The construction I have in mind is

> First, I consider the relation between mass and energy, which, paraphrasing, says that ...

Is this construct acceptable?

In the second quote, *relation* stands for *mathematical relation* in specific reference to an equation. A more accurate example is the following

> First, I consider the equation relating mass to energy, which, paraphrasing, says that ...

Bonus question: which or that?

Comment: In my opinion, your second example is more along the lines of a true paraphrase. **Paraphrase**: _express the meaning of something using different words, esp. to achieve greater clarity_ (NOAD).

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the several errors in "I stumbled [this][1] joke".  By "stumbled" do you mean you don't understand, or you encountered?  Was "[this][1]" supposed to link somewhere?  Are you referring to something in your first quote as a joke?  If so specifically point out which words are the joke.  Note, [Ginsberg's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginsberg%27s_Theorem), which what you quote is a mangled version of, contains three statements of fact based on laws of thermodynamics, and though some may think them funny they are not actually a joke.

Comment: You're confusing metaphor with paraphrase.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're actually making an adjective clause, the overriding consideration should be the word *relation*.

In the previous joke that you cited, the noun being used is *law*, as in "Law of Thermodynamics."

If you're going to continue using "*relation*" (or relationship) as your noun:

> I consider the **relation** between mass and energy, which

Unlike with the noun *law*, it doesn't work so well to say "paraphrase a relation." So it's better to use an expression other than *paraphrase*.

Perhaps something along the lines of:

- simply put/ put simply
- in layman's terms/ in simple terms

etc.

Either this or use the noun "law" as in the original.

Comment: Oh... I didn't realize the "paraphrasing a relation" part.

Comment: @Ryogi, if you do a quick search, the word "relationship" will mostly appear with "mass" and "energy." But yes, "relation" is also possible. IMO, the relationships will be defined through "laws," and the laws can then be paraphrased. The thing is, most people are familiar with the things you wanna talk about as the "Laws of Thermodynamics," so it would be alienating and confusing to call them differently

Answer (score 0):

For the last sentence, the correct thing to say would be "which, on paraphrasing, shows that" or "which, on paraphrasing, reveals that". You're trying to show that an action has been done upon the "relation", which results in what you proceed to say.

Both "which" and "that" are acceptable, but when you use "which," you need a phrase after it, so it should be followed by a comma. IF you use "that," you don't need to, since it's a clause.